# how to add JSON editor in extjs 3.4

Tags: extjs, extjs3

I am using extjs  3.4 .I have a from which contain along J SON value , i want to edit this value after that i want to validate the J SON .please tell me how can i do this.
here is the code for the json edit from :

```
 var editJsonPanel = new Ext.form.FormPanel({

        id: "nosqlFP",
        baseCls: 'x-plain',
        labelWidth: 120,
        defaultType: 'textfield',
        monitorValid:true,
        bodyStyle: ' padding: 15px; background-color: #ffffff' ,
        items:[new Ext.form.TextArea({
            id:"editJsonDocumentId",
            fieldLabel: 'JsonDocument',
            allowBlank: false,
            name: 'jsonDocument',
            anchor: '90%',
            value: json
        })],
        listeners : {
            render : function(form){
            }
        },
        buttonAlign: 'center',
        buttons: []

    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ext JS does not have any build in JSON validator. However if you just want to know if string is valid JSON or not you can use `try/catch` block and [`Ext.util.JSON.decode`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.util.JSON-method-decode) method.

```
function isValidJSON(str) {
    try {
        Ext.util.JSON.decode(str);
    } catch (e) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```